# Reset user lastSeen property in Actions on Google simulator

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I need to document a process for our QA team to reliably test the on-boarding and returning user processes in the Actions on Google simulator. I have tried clearing the browser cookies, logging out, and reseting the simulator. Short of setting up new users in the project permissions I'm not sure what to do.

UPDATE
To clarify,I'm referring to the User object in the [AppRequest](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#User) response. The application is not yet live. I would like to use the [Simulator](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/simulator) for testing not Assistant on the device.

Comment: Hello, I am not really sure to understand your question but in "Dialogflow > Analytics tab > Session flow" you can check the user flow and so the user actions for your application.

Comment: @JordanMontel I've updated the original question. Thanks for your suggestion but the Analytics tab is just Chatbase analytics and not associated with the Simulator.

Answer (score 5):

Use the Google app on your phone to go to the directory entry for your Action. Then click reset app. (That was the old title, it might say forget me or something like that now). In any case, that should reset the user vis-a-vis the Action to square one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The action is still development so I don't have a directory listing currently.

Comment: Even if it's in development if you have your agent's account in your device you can test it in the Assistant.

Comment: "Reset" is a small blue link at the bottom of the directory entry in case you have trouble finding it!

Comment: Publishing an alpha release in the Actions console will get you a link to your Action which you can then reset.